# How can I display image in screen center?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image] [image]

I want to display the image like first image but my images are displaying like second image. 
I want to display images like first image, like center in screen and equal spaces top and bottom look first image, but my images are displaying not center in screen and no spaces in top.

What can I do for display image like first images... 
Anybody knows,please give solution for that
**Thanks All**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set `android:scaleType="center"` to your `ImageView` for ImageBitmap,
or set `android:layout_gravity="center"` to your `ImageView` for its layout in his parents.